# Using Team CIty's rest API to pull more information per build in a builds array

Tags: javascript, html, api, knockout.js, teamcity

As mentioned in the title I am using Knockout JS, HTML, and CSS to create a monitor for builds on the Teamcity server.

It was coming along well until I reached an issue with panels that display the latest build of each type (deploy, selenium tests, and compile)

The issue is that the Team city API url that I am using retrieves a list of information about each build including the status, name, description and type, but does not provide me with a "Triggered" variable.

The API url I am currently using is as follows:

```
Settings.buildsUrl = Settings.proxy + Settings.teamCityUrl + '/guestAuth/app/rest/builds?locator=running:any,branch:branched:any,count:20';
```

Within my HTML, I have the following foreach which is meant to display the main panel of the latest build, but as there is no 'triggered' inside the XML from TeamCity, I cannot display who triggered the current build.

```
<div class="dev-panel-history">
    <ul data-bind="foreach: { data: mostRecentDevs }">
            <li data-bind="attr: { class: lowerStatus() }, css: { running: isRunning() }">
                <div class="build-branch"  data-bind="text: description()"></div>
                <div class="build-type" data-bind="text: buildType"></div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <div class="build-status" data-bind="text: isRunning() ? '' : status"></div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <!-- ko if: hasProgress() -->
                   <div class="progress-container" data-bind="attr: { 'data-progress' : percentageComplete() }"></div>
                <!-- /ko -->
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: So, I need a href added to the REST API which is getting the builds array, and this should give me more parameters in this API call. But I am a bit unsure as to what that href is and where I would find it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to make additional calls for each build, but you need to craft how you want the response returned. There's a query string parameter called **fields** that lets you define what you want to bring back.

e.g. to return the triggered data in your original call you can add **&fields=build(triggered)** to your original request

```
teamCityUrl + '/guestAuth/app/rest/builds?locator=running:any,branch:branched:any,count:20&fields=build(triggered)';
```

This would return something like this

```
<builds>
  <build>
    <triggered type="user" date="20160314T130743+0000">
      <user/>
    </triggered>
  </build>
  <build>
    <triggered type="vcs" details="jetbrains.git" date="20160221T230257+0000"/>
  </build>
</builds>
```

The caveat to this is that you now have to exclusively define what you want returned. So to return all the other fields and the trigger data, add this parameter to the query string

```
&fields=build(id,buildTypeId,number,status,state,branchName,defaultBranch,href,webUrl,buildTypeId,triggered)
```

TeamCity documentation - [Full and Partial responses](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/REST+API#RESTAPI-FullandPartialResponses)

Hope this helps

Comment: Or, for all available information at the same time: `fields=*,build(*)`

Comment: Current documentation link for [Full and Partial Responses](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/rest/teamcity-rest-api-documentation.html#Full+and+Partial+Responses)